# Am I using the PHP.js strpbrk function properly?

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following JS function:

```
function validatePass()
{
    var oldPass = document.getElementById("oldpass").value;
    var newPass1 = document.getElementById("newpass1").value;
    var newPass2 = document.getElementById("newpass2").value;
    if(strpbrk(newPass1,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") != false)
    {
        document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneLowercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"green\">Met</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneLowercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"red\">Not Met</span>";
    }
    if(strpbrk(newPass1,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") != false)
    {
        document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneUppercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"green\">Met</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneUppercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"red\">Not Met</span>";
    }
    if(strpbrk(newPass1,"1234567890") != false)
    {
        document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneNumber").innerHTML = "<span id=\"green\">Met</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneNumber").innerHTML = "<span id=\"red\">Not Met</span>";
    }
}
```

That code makes a call to the PHP.js function [strpbrk](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript%5Fequivalent%5Ffor%5Fphps%5Fstrpbrk/) to determine if newPass1 contains acceptable data.  In PHP, strpbrk searches to see if the `haystack` contains any of the chars in the `char_list`.  However, in this JS implementation, it searches for all of the chars.  How can I make it behave the way I want to?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using regex instead of strpbrk.

```
function validatePass()
{
    var oldPass = document.getElementById("oldpass").value;
    var newPass1 = document.getElementById("newpass1").value;
    var newPass2 = document.getElementById("newpass2").value;
    if(/[a-z]/.test(newpass1))
    {
            document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneLowercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"green\">Met</span>";
    }
    else
    {
            document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneLowercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"red\">Not Met</span>";
    }
    if(/[A-Z]/.test(newpass1))
    {
            document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneUppercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"green\">Met</span>";
    }
    else
    {
            document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneUppercaseLetter").innerHTML = "<span id=\"red\">Not Met</span>";
    }
    if(/[0-9]/.test(newpass1))
    {
            document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneNumber").innerHTML = "<span id=\"green\">Met</span>";
    }
    else
    {
            document.getElementById("ContainsAtLeastOneNumber").innerHTML = "<span id=\"red\">Not Met</span>";
    }
}
```